# Jetty is not extracting my WAR file into temp directory. How can I stop it from extracting or make sure it extracts to the temp directory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

In a spring-boot app, how do I stop Jetty from extracting the War file ?

I want to stop Jetty from extracting the War because the directory where it is supposed to be extracted is always empty.  I thought stopping Jetty from extracting and use the WAR file as-is may be an option but I have added jetty-web.xml to my /WEB-INF/ directory but it did not help.

jetty-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC
        "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
        "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

Jetty doesn't seem to look at this setting.

Jetty logs:
Started o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@bfe845{/app,[file:///apps/app-1/tmp/jetty-docbase.8731890992893272407.8888/],AVAILABLE}

But the directory: /apps/app-1/tmp/jetty-docbase.8731890992893272407.8888/ is always empty.

Why didn't Jetty populate this directory?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Lee

Answer (score 0):

`/apps/app-1/tmp/jetty-docbase.8731890992893272407.8888/` is your work directory for that webapp.

If you set `<Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>` then it's only used for work files during runtime, not for extracted content of your webapp.   This is mandatory, part of the Servlet spec, and cannot be avoided.

Your XML is incomplete (missing war reference and contextPath setting) and invalid (dtd reference).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC
        "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
        "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="war">/path/to/your/app.war</Set>
    <Set name="contextPath">/myapp</Set>
    <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
</Configure>
```